How to redirect user back to *ViewSet after creating item via the "Add <ItemType>" action on *ViewSet listing?
I am migrating our content from Wagtail ModelAdmin to the new *ViewSet approach. I notice that the new *ViewSet allows users to define new items via a button along the top saying "Add "

After successfully adding the new item, the user is redirected in the Wagtail Admin to the location of that item in the Wagtail Pages menu (page tree). However, this is disorienting, since the page tree listing may often differ from the *ViewSet display, such as having different columns, actions, etc.

I was expecting that the user would be redirected to the related *ViewSet so they would have continuity in the user experience.

How can I ensure users are redirected to the related viewset after creating an item from the viewset "Add ..." action button?
